# how to get the count of available Physical serial port

Tags: linux, serial-port

How we get the count of total number of physically available serial ports in a Linux machine.

Is there any particular command for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the`setserial` command to get this info, with the -g flag:

```
[{0} 20:18:12] $ sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS*
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
```

This works with the assumption that they are correctly configured and the device has a link created in /dev/  That is typical but there is always a chance you have some multi-port serial card that exposes its serial ports in a nonstandard way. On this machine I only have one physical port, and its the one with a 16550A style UART associated with it; so you could just filter the output with grep:

```
[{0} 20:18:45] $ sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS* | grep "16550A"
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
```

If you literally want a count, then use the -c flag with grep:

```
[{0} 20:18:45] $ sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS* | grep -c "16550A"
1
```

You may not need to use sudo; depends on the permissions on your serial ports; I don't use this one and haven't changed them. `setserial` isn't installed by default on most distros but should be available from your package manager. If not here is an alternative (assuming that your dmesg log didn't rotate messages from boot out already).

```
[{0} 20:19:13] $ dmesg | grep "16550A"
[    0.962785] 00:08: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
```

Similar option if you have a systemd based distro:

```
[{0} 20:19:43] $ sudo journalctl | grep 16550A
Apr 22 20:59:44 lenny kernel: 00:08: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
```

Comment: dmesg|grep ttyS will also give same

Comment: I am working as integrator.in my system i can't find out any physical serial port.but when i check with setserial command it showing ttyS0.thats why i ask this question

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by these two comments. I think I answered  your question, as best i can tell. Your question asked for a simple command to get a list of the physical serial ports on the system and I provided 3 methods to get that. If it wasn't physically there, it would not be assigned an IRQ nor be configured as a UART 16550A. If you are trying to map /dev/ttyS* devices to specific physical ports on your motherboard / chassis, that's a different question, but also answerable.